# Why don't my radishes swell up?

Tags: vegetables, diagnosis, root-vegetables, growth, radishes

When I grow radishes, I find that some of them don't swell up to form the globe I expect; instead the root stays thin.  These are planted in the same bed and at the same time as radishes that **do** swell.  I believe I'm doing everything right: cultivating the soil before planting, thinning the seedlings, keeping them well watered (when Mother Nature doesn't do it for me) and rotating crops from year to year.

What can I do to make **all** of my radishes plump and juicy?

Comment: What varieties are you growing?  E.g. I've never had a problem with cherry belles.  But I must be doing something wrong with my daikons because some of those swell and some don't.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've had it be that case that all of my radishes failed to plump and that was because I failed to properly cultivate my soil and left them to grow between craggy, rocky, ugly soil.

So... As Shanna says, perhaps there's nothing you can do to make them all plump up.  But there is plenty you can do to screw them all up so be vigilant.

Answer (score 12):

You're certainly doing everything right if most of your radishes end up being plump and delicious!  But you're always going to get a few thin ones mixed in with the normally-shaped roots due to the nature of plant reproduction and genetics.  There's nothing you can do to make those radishes plump up.